# cant get json object to show using ajax/jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I don't know much about JSON and have never been able to return something with JSON into ajax and show it using jquery despite of my many tries.
What I am trying to do is, send data using JSON object to the ajax while loading the profile of a user.
**[Updated] php code**:

```
<?php include(dirname(__FILE__). '/../script/config.php');
session_start();
$id = $_POST['u_search'];
$email = $_SESSION['Email'];

foreach($pdo->query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE ID='$id'") as $row) {
    //$firstname = $row['FirstName'];
    //$lastname = $row['LastName'];
    $pic = $row['Pic'];
    $id = $row['ID'];
    $u_email = $row['Email'];
}
$firstname = "Jason";
    $lastname = "Born";
    $data = array("success"=> true,"inpt"=>"<p>Hello there! I am " . $firstname . " " . $lastname . "</p>");
    echo json_encode($data);
header("Content-Type: application/json");)
?>

<?php $pdo = null; ?>
```

**Updated Ajax**:

```
function op_prof(obj) {
    var value = obj.id;
    var dataString = "{'u_search':'"+value+"'}";
    $("#co_profile").show();
    $(".searchbox").val('');
    $("#usr_suggest").hide();

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/script/profile.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
        alert(console.log(data));
        alert(data);
        $("#co_profile").html(data.inpt).show();
        location.hash = 'profile' + 'id=' + dataString;
    }
  });
};
```

edit: When I use `dataType: 'json'` , nothing in `success` runs but when I remove it, they run..
edit: When I use `datatype: 'json'` instead of `dataType: 'json'` the codes in `success` run. I used `alert(console.log(data));` , it says "undefined"

edit: I am using `//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js`

Comment: First try to `console.log(data)` in `success` and print log in your question.

Comment: I am able to load json data Properly in my example with your preference. If you want I can share it. But first show your console.log(data).

Comment: Nothing in `success` runs .. thats wired .. I have put `console.log(data);` in success

Comment: But when I remove `dataType: 'json'` , everything in `success` runs

Comment: If you run your profile.php file then does it shows any error? Because I have doubt on use of `'$id'` and `'$pic'` in your first condition.

Comment: The `$pic` and `$id` is set using a query.. If I use `datatype:'json'` instead of `dataType:'json'` the codes in `success` runs.

Comment: try `alert(dataString)` and see if the data you are receiving is a valid json string.

Comment: when I use `alert(dataString)` , the result is `{'u_search':'1'}`

Comment: If you ur getting correct alert then is should work and correct syntax to specify `json` is `dataType:'json'`.

Comment: hmm.. @NullVoid when I use the correct syntax, the codes in `success` don't run. is there any possible explanataion for this? thank you

Comment: No need to explanation about `dataType:'json'` because it's the true way to specify `dataType` for requested output. Can you updated your jQuery code after your trial?

Comment: Ok. Just put this code in your profile.php and see what it returns `$firstname = "Jason "; $lastname = "Born";
$data = array("success"=> true,"inpt"=>"<p>Hello there! I am " . $firstname . " " . $lastname . "</p>");
echo json_encode($data);`

Comment: Still .. nothing in `success` runs

Comment: What do you mean by "Then only execute profile.php **with you true path**" ?

Comment: Then try to execute only profile.php with you true path and it should print {"success":true,"inpt":"<p>Hello there! I am Jason Born<\/p>"} from profile.php and I am getting this output as Object {success: true, inpt: "<p>Hello there! I am Jason Born</p>"} in success. The way to track that profile.php is executing proper json output.

Comment: Hello there! I am Jason Born<\/p>"}{"success":true,"inpt":"Hello there! I am Jason Born<\/p>"} <-- that is what I get when I remove `dataType` .. but when I add it back, nothing happens

Comment: Actually this should not happen. You should get json output with `dataType:'json'`. Because your code is perfectly working for me on my machine.

Comment: If you're using jQuery version < 1.8 then try with this next to success handler 
`error: function(xhr, status, thrown){
 console.log(status);
 console.log(thrown);
}`

Comment: @NullVoid if I have the `dataType` as json, the `error` and `success` doesn't show.

Comment: It's really a strange thing. Because everything is fine with `$.ajax and json` call. Which jQuery version you're using?

Comment: There might be a problem in the php then I guess .. let me update the php code

Comment: Updated the php code @NullVoid

Comment: Then might be some issue with jQuery's 2.0 version and json call.

Comment: Should I try the 1.9.1 version? Or can you suggest a working one?

Comment: Try to use 1.9.1 and also check with its Doc where you will find its example so you can update your json code accordingly and show your result.

Comment: @NullVoid which library do you use? I am still unable to fix the errors

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 1):

if you put datatype:json means you have to send data:"" in json string format and even in the server side the variable name should match, so that it can read the value which you have sent.

example:

```
datatype:'json',
data : JSON.stringify({'u_search':'value'})
```

used JSON.js file for converting object to string.

Answer (score 1):

```
var dataString = "{'u_search':'"+value+"'}";

dataType: 'json',
data: dataString,
```

**Edit:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$.post("/script/profile.php",{dataString:dataString},function(data){
                alert(console.log(data));
    alert(data);
    $("#co_profile").html(data.inpt).show();
    location.hash = 'profile' + 'id=' + dataString;
            }, "json");   // USing JSON here for the returned value from server...
```

**In your profile.php file you must be decoding the json format. Remember to collect the decoded json value in a variable with name dataString**